# Create nested custom angular web components

Tags: angular, nested, web-component

I am creating multiple custom web components in order to reuse them in multiple projects, which works fine. Since we want them originally to be independent, I use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native`. So, each one of those web components is creating it's own shadow-root which contains the template of the component.

I am trying now to create more complex web components which are using ones that I already created earlier. As soon as I build, package and run this on a http-server, it doesn't work and chrome displays this error in the console : `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createShadowRoot' on 'Element': Shadow root cannot be created on a host which already hosts a shadow tree.`

So after searching a bit on the internet, I found out that it isn't allowed to have nested shadow-roots. Since every custom web component is creating its own shadow-root, how can I manage to re-use my components in more complex ones ?

[Edit / Additionnal infos]

I use

```
const myCustomEl= createCustomElement(CustomElComponent, { injector });
```

and then

```
customElements.define('custom-el', myCustomEl);
```

and then I build it and package it with

```
 jscat ./dist/framework/runtime.js ./dist/framework/polyfills.js ./dist/framework/scripts.js ./dist/framework/main.js > miZipFramework.js.gz
```

before I run it on my http-server

Comment: How are you building this library and how are you consuming the library. This should have nothing to do with `encapsulation` settings of a component. I would guess that you've loading the library twice and the library is trying to attach to a DOM element already used by a component. There isn't enough here for us to help you.

Comment: I use `const myCustomEl= createCustomElement(CustomElComponent, { injector });` and then `customElements.define('custom-el', myCustomEl);` and then I build it and package it with `jscat ./dist/framework/runtime.js ./dist/framework/polyfills.js ./dist/framework/scripts.js ./dist/framework/main.js > miZipFramework.js.gz` before I run it on my http-server

Comment: Note that Angular [currently only supports Shadow DOM v0](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23636) that is [only supported in Chrome](https://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdom). I recommend you stick to `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` until they add v1 support.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem and the only thing that worked for me was changing encapsulation from `Native` to `Emulated`.

I also found info about this problem here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24397

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.